# Why are some items in my HTML & CSS not linking?

Tags: html, css

Below is my HTML:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Animal Trading Cards</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

```
<div id="card">

    <h1 class="title">Tiger</h1>

    <img class="picture" src="tiger.jpg" alt="Tiger">

    <div id="card-info">

        <p class="fact">The tiger is the largest cat species.</p>

        <ul class="list">

            <li><span class="label">Scientific Name</span>: Panthera tigris</li>

            <li><span class="label">Average Weight</span>: 485 pounds</li>

            <li><span class="label">Average Lifespan</span>: 10-15 years</li>

            <li><span class="label">Habitat</span>: Forests, grasslands, swamps, and woodlands</li>

        </ul>

        <p> A Tiger is a powerful carnivore, a hunter with sharp teeth, strong jaws, and a very agile body. They are the largest naturally occurring species of cat, of which the Siberian tiger is the largest, weighing up to 800 pounds and measuring up to 11 feet head to tail.</p>

    </div>

</div>
```

My CSS is below. My image in my code, for example, is not changing size. Items that should be italicized are not...

```
html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#card {
width: 300px;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
box-shadow: 5px 5px
}

.title {
font-weight: bold;
}

.picture {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

#card-info {
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.fact {
font-style: italic;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.label {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Sorry, completely new to this. Its my first post! I believe I actually go the two to link properly after putting them in a separate folder on my desktop.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include all *relevant* code in the question - specifically, your CSS.

Comment: You might want to consider using a `<dl>` instead of a `<ul>` for that list and note that `class="list"` seems redundant on a list element, and that there is a `label` element (with entirely different meaning) so having a `label` class may cause confusion.

Comment: @Utkanos submitted an edit to have the image displaying

Comment: [Pictures of code are unhelpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), include your code as *text*, preferably using the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: Still no CSS in the question - please post code, not pictures of code.

Comment: @Quentin I agree ; however, the user has to do that himself, won't bother "translate" the image to text

Comment: I really appreciate everyone's help. Sorry, completely new to this as it is my first post. I believe I was able to get this working. What is the best way to state that this have been resolved so I don't take more of your time?

Answer (score 0):

**To change image size,**

```
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**To change font size for your class label,**

```
.label {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

**To change your text italic, for your class label,**

```
.label {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

*If you used these and still doesn't show in your webpage, it may be because, you are using css in separate file, `styles.css` . So, may be your browser doesn't sync latest css data and still using old caches. (recommened to use firefox browser or press ctrl+F5 to refresh the page in chrome)*

Comment: Please see [answer], especially the part headed "Answer well asked questions" -- this question is not well asked as its code is included as an image, leaving people with visual impairments at a significant disadvantage.